# Unable to map an array in ReactJS , results in non iterable error

Tags: reactjs

im currently using react.js for my project. Im facing an issue whereby im unable to render a list .  The error is :

```
index.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
```

This is my code which tries to render the data :

```
                    <Row justify="center" align="middle" style={{padding:50}}>
                {(this.props.transition_approvals_hooks).map(hook => (<WorkflowAutomationList key={hook.id} {...hook} />))}
                </Row>
```

This is the data format :

```
[{…}]
0:
callback_function: {id: 1, name: "print date", body: "from datetime import datetime
def handle(context):
    print(datetime.now())", version: 1, date_created: "2020-05-24T06:14:42.211722Z", …}
id: 1
object_id: null
transition: null
transition_meta: 1
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: what `transition_approvals_hooks` look like?

Comment: You posted the wrong code, I don't see you trying to spread an itterable.

Comment: Hello , i figured out the mistake , there was another loop within my inner component from a package that i was using . Therefore it tried to run iterate over the already mapped data which is not an iterable

Answer (score 0):

Use destructuring to store the data in a prop and then pass it -

```
<WorkflowAutomationList key={hook.id} data=[...hook] />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to iterate rows using the data.
Shouldn't the row be inside loop. e.g.:

```
{props.rows.map((x,i) => <Row key={i} data={x} />) }
```

May be it will help.